# how to add a border around canvas wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to add border around canvas element? Border should be same size as canvas.

I am using below code for this, but couldn't able to achieve the result.

```
 <Canvas Background="Transparent" Margin="69,-30,56,315" x:Name="LetterCanvas" >
 <Border x:Name="CanvasBorder" BorderThickness="5" Height="271" Width="325">
 </Border></Canvas>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to place the `Border` outside of the `Canvas`:

```
<Border>
  <Canvas>
  </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Comment: how to add color to the Border? I couldn't find the property.

Comment: Color => BorderBrush, 
Thickness => BorderThickness

Greets